# Алгоритм заполнения ProgressBar по содержанию Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм, textbox

Помогите пожалуйста придумать алгоритм, чтобы progressBar заполнялся на половину (`progressBar.Maximum / 2`) при `textBox != string.Empty`. Нам пригодится событие TextBox-a `_TextChanged`. Но я страшно запутался с флагами) Пользователь должен ввести что-либо в `textBox`, прогресс бар при этом заполнился.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void tb_Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tb_Name.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            if (!isHalf)
            {
                pb.Value += (pb.Maximum / 2);
                isHalf = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pb.Value -= (pb.Maximum / 2);
            isHalf = false;
        }
    }
```